# Celery chaining executing subtask before group tasks completed

Tags: python, celery

What I am trying to do is execute a group of tasks and have the result of each task in the group sent to another task and then the results of all those tasks sent to one final task.

e.g.

```
jobgroup = (
           group(tasks.task1.s(p) for p in params) |
           tasks.dmap.s(tasks.task2.s())
          )
```

That part works OK for me but the problem I am having is if I am trying to get all the results into one final task e.g.

```
mychain = chain(jobgroup | tasks.task3.s())
```

What I am seeing is that task3() is being called while tasks from task2 are still in the pending status by printing out the status as they come in (the following snippet is what I am print from within my task3 function:

```
@task()
def task3(input):
   for item in input.results:
      logger.info(item.status)
```

Log results

```
[2014-09-04 10:48:41,905: INFO/Worker-7] tasks.task3[27053688-3c5c-4ca5-975f-356a66d55364]: PENDING
[2014-09-04 10:48:41,905: INFO/Worker-7] tasks.task3[27053688-3c5c-4ca5-975f-356a66d55364]: PENDING
```

So how do I set this up so that task3 is not called until all the tasks in jobgroup are complete?

Comment: Something else I have noticed here too is that the parent tasks completes and returns all the results as expect however my task3 still have the item as pending

Answer (score 1):

**[Chord](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.html?highlight=group#celery.chord):**

`A chord consists of a header and a body. The header is a group of tasks that MUST COMPLETE before the callback is called. A chord is essentially a callback for a group of tasks.`

**Example:**

```
>>> from celery import chord
>>> res = chord([add.s(2, 2), add.s(4, 4)])(sum_task.s())
```

You can use `chord` to accomplish the task.

```
from celery import chord, group, chain

task_1 = group(tasks.task1.s(p) for p in params)
task_2 = group(tasks.dmap.s(tasks.task2.s())
task_3 = tasks.task3.s()

workflow = chord(chain([task_1, task_2]))(task_3)
```

Comment: Chord is throwing this: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 108, in <module>
    workflow = chord([task_1, task_2])(task_3)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/celery/canvas.py", line 611, in __call__
    return self.apply_async((), {'body': body} if body else {}, **options)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/celery/canvas.py", line 602, in apply_async
    _chord = self.type
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/celery/canvas.py", line 590, in type
    app = self.tasks[0].type.app
AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'type'

Comment: Just to be sure here is the full sample app: https://gist.github.com/sinkers/d4e0bcac5f226e8bcc21 

>celery --version
3.1.13 (Cipater)

Comment: @Andrew Since task_1 is list of tasks, groupjob has to be used. Modified the code. Can you try again?

Comment: Am getting an error in the worker log now:

[2014-09-06 16:32:23,142: ERROR/Worker-2] Chord callback '1059e974-ad4c-4177-a894-fc410b9edd7b' raised: ValueError('1059e974-ad4c-4177-a894-fc410b9edd7b',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/celery/backends/base.py", line 543, in on_chord_part_return
    raise ValueError(gid)
ValueError: 1059e974-ad4c-4177-a894-fc410b9edd7b

Comment: @Andrew task_2 & task_1 has to be chained together. Its working now.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Either my dmap complains about not being passed enough args using the example above, if I add workflow = chord(chain([task_1 | task_2]))(task_3) then it runs but task3 fails to get called.